# Nav Bar + Index (Popover)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to make an iPad's app, and so far I made a Nav bar controller with one button "Next" which passes from one viewcontroller to the following. But I'd like to give the user the option of "jumping" from one viewcontroller to another, with an index. So I think that  what I need is a popover or a table view. But the rows of this table would have to load their respective viewcontrollers. How can I do that ?

Thank you!

PS1: I'm not using storyboards
PS2: It can't mess up with the nav bar controller!
PS3: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

If you use a table, use didSelectedRowAtIndexPath to select row and then push the correspondent view controller. Id a popover with buttons is chosed, for each buton se a method which push the view controller (or set a tag for each button and use [sender tag] to know which view controller must be pushed).

Comment: In the first case, I shall use a table view and not a table view controller, right ? So, if I put a table in the first view controller, how can I manage to this table appear in all the view controllers ?

Comment: You can create a specific class with a delegate which can be called from each view.